# Multiple assembly conflict with NuGet System references

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a project that references [this NuGet package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/2.3.0) The package has several framework references (e.g., `System.Collections`). My project is targeting .NET Framework 4.6.2, and I have the .NET 4.6.2 targeting pack installed on my build machine.

When I install the NuGet package in Visual studio, it also installs dependencies for all the framework packages, so my `packages.config` ends up looking like this

```
<packages>
  <package id="CommandLineParser" version="2.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net462" />
</packages>
```

I've read that this is because the package targets .NET Standard, which will automatically import all these packages even if they are present on the machine.

So far, everything is fine, and I can build the project on my machine. However, on the build server, I get the following error

> CSC : error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C:\Jenkins\jobs\MyProject\workspace\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.1.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll' and 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Remove one of the duplicate references.

The build server also has the .NET 4.6.2 targeting pack installed. Moreover, on my dev machine, I also have the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6.2\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
```

as well as all the other facade system files.

So my question is, why does this fail on my build server? It seems like all the same versions of .NET are installed, and I'm not sure what else to check.

Comment: What is the MSBuild version that executes the build on your build server? Use Visual Studio 2017 or its Build Tools (aka MSBuild 15) and try again.

Comment: The `msbuild` version is 14.0.23107.0. I don't have access to Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 on the build server, and now the project builds without issue. I'm not totally sure what the change was that fixed the error, unfortunately.